# Finding Values That Are One Different From A Grabbag Table Of Values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like the below

```
**Col1  Col2**
ABC  XYZ
ABC  A12
DEF  XYZ
DEF  A12
DEF  ADB
```

There are hundreds of distinct values in Col1, which can have 2-50 distinct values in Col2. I need to find the pairs of supersets of Col1 that have 1 and only 1 Col2 value different from another set.

Example: ABC contains (XYZ, A12) and DEF contains (XYZ, A12, and ADB).
Therefore, DEF is a superset of ABC, with the single additional value of ADB.

I need to generate a table similar to the below:

```
**SUPERSET  SUBSET  ADDL**
DEF  ABC  ADB
```

And i have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Ideally, you should be doing SQL tutorials, trying your and at your task, then posting any failing code here.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you take a cartesian product of your codes, then you can see if B has no members not in A, but A has members not in B, so A would then be a superset of B

```
 SELECT DISTINCT y1.col1 Superset, y2.col1 subset  from YourTable y1, YourTable y2 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y3 WHERE y3.col1 = y2.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y4 WHERE y4.col1 = y1.col1
                )
     AND EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y5 WHERE y5.col1 = y1.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y6 WHERE y6.col1 = y2.col1
                )
```

you could try, to check if there is only 1 additional element
(From B that is not in A) = 0 item AND (FROM A that is not in B) = 1 item

```
SELECT DISTINCT y1.col1 Superset, y2.col1 subset  from YourTable y1, YourTable y2 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y3 WHERE y3.col1 = y2.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y4 WHERE y4.col1 = y1.col1
                )
     AND   1 = (SELECT count(1) as x FROM (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y5 WHERE y5.col1 = y1.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y6 WHERE y6.col1 = y2.col1) DQ
                )
```

to get also the additional value, them maybe

```
SELECT DISTINCT y1.col1 Superset, y2.col1 subset, DQ3.col2  from YourTable y1, YourTable y2 
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DQ2.col2 FROM (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y5 WHERE y5.col1 = y1.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y6 WHERE y6.col1 = y2.col1) DQ2) DQ3 
        WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y3 WHERE y3.col1 = y2.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y4 WHERE y4.col1 = y1.col1
                )
     AND   1 = (SELECT count(1) as x FROM (SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y5 WHERE y5.col1 = y1.col1 
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT col2 FROM YourTable y6 WHERE y6.col1 = y2.col1) DQ
                )
```

Comment: This unfortunately returns for any subset. I need only those that have 1 additional value in difference. But thanks, i am going to play with and try to modify this to narrow it down.

Comment: try my second code where the count of additional elements (with no missing elements) is 1

Comment: I needed to add an alias 'DQ' to my inner query in my sub-query

Comment: yeah, I had to add the alias. The results look good, validating several and it looks good. Now i am trying to grab the value out of y5 to add it to the main query as an additional column. It is the value that is different between the super and sub sets. Thanks again!

Comment: I was trying something similar with a cross apply. In both cases the y1.col1 cannot be referenced inside the apply.  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "y1.PANEL_ID" could not be bound.

Comment: For whatever reason, dumping the results into a temp table then doing a cross apply on that, seems to have worked. Thanks @Cato, this worked great.